# DataType errors loading Excel to SQL via Python using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to load a CSV file into Oracle via Python using SQLAlchemy. I am routinely getting the error "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CLOB" and have ben unable to solve.

```
headers = ['LINE_START_DATE', 'LINE_END_DATE']
dtypes = {'LINE_START_DATE': 'str', 'LINE_END_DATE': 'str'}
parse_dates = ['LINE_START_DATE', 'LINE_END_DATE']
df = pd.read_csv(processpath+filename, sep=',',index_col=False, dtype=dtypes, names=headers, parse_dates=parse_dates)
engine = create_engine('oracle://'+username+':'+password+database)
df.to_sql(table, con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

There are many more date columns than just the two above, but just going one column at a time to try to find the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `df.to_sql(… , dtype={"LINE_START_DATE": Date, "LINE_END_DATE": Date})` where `Date` is `from sqlalchemy import Date`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.